# Need to clone XML doc many times with increasing values

Tags: xml, rest, xslt, scripting

I have an XML doc that forms part of an automated REST test step. I need to clone the step about a thousand times, but there is one key value in the document that needs to be unique for each clone. What's the best way - script, tool or whatever, that I can use to copy it over and over but change that one value for every instance? I thought about attempting to write a java program to do this but I have no experience dealing with XML in java and my understanding is that the parsing is a pain.

Update: currently investigating XSLT and whether it would fit this need. If you have any input or knowledge, please share.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 2.0 would be fine for this. (If you need an XSLT 2.0 processor, I would recommend [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/).)

For example, this simple XML document:

```
<doc>
    <foo/>
    <bar id="orig-id"/>
</doc>
```

and this XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="threshold" select="10"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="clone">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="clone"/>          
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/bar/@id" mode="clone">
        <xsl:param name="doc-id" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="id" select="$doc-id"/> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="createDocs">
        <xsl:param name="dashNbr" select="1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="doc-id" select="concat(generate-id(),'-',$dashNbr)"/>
        <xsl:result-document href="{$doc-id}.xml">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/*" mode="clone">
                <xsl:with-param name="doc-id" select="$doc-id" tunnel="yes"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>          
        </xsl:result-document>
        <xsl:if test="$threshold > $dashNbr">
            <xsl:call-template name="createDocs">
                <xsl:with-param name="dashNbr" select="$dashNbr + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces 10 files with unique `id` attributes. The file names are based on the id.

Examples:

d1-1.xml

```
<doc>
   <foo/>
   <bar id="d1-1"/>
</doc>
```

d1-2.xml

```
<doc>
   <foo/>
   <bar id="d1-2"/>
</doc>
```

d1-10.xml

```
<doc>
   <foo/>
   <bar id="d1-10"/>
</doc>
```

You would only need to change the value of the `threshold` param to the number of files you want created and change the `match` for the attribute you want to modify.